# Expectation of a Wiener process at a Stopping Time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I am working through an answer to the following question and do not understand  an expectation which takes place at the end.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Define the following stochastic process
\begin{align}
\tilde{W}(t) := W(t) + \int_{0}^{t} e^{W(s)}\mathbb{1}_{\{|W(s)\le 1\}}\,ds \quad \forall \, t \in [0,T]
\end{align}

For the stopping time $\tau := \inf\{t \ge 0 : |W(t)| = 1\}$ compute $\mathbb{E}_{P}[\tilde{W}(\tau)]$.

\begin{align}
\end{align}

Being as concise as possible the results I have so far are:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_P[W(\tau)] &= -1P(W(\tau) = -1) + 1P(W(\tau) = 1)\\
&= -1\tfrac{1}{2} + 1\tfrac{1}{2}\\
&= 0
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_P[\tilde{W}(\tau)] &= \mathbb{E}_P\left[W(\tau) + \int_{0}^{\tau} e^{W(s)}\mathbb{1}_{\{|W(s)\le 1\}}\,ds \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{W(s)}\,ds\right]
\end{align}
From ito,
\begin{align}
e^{W(s)} &= 1 + \int_{0}^{t} e^{W(s)}dW(s) + \tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}e^{W(s)}\,ds
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\tau} e^{W(s)}ds = 2e^{W(\tau)} -2 - 2\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{W(s)}dW(s) 
\end{align}

For brevity let us assume $\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{W(s)}dW(s)] = 0$.

Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{\tau} e^{W(s)}ds\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[2e^{W(\tau)} -2 - 2\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{W(s)}dW(s) \right]\\
&= 2\mathbb{E}\left[e^{W(\tau)} \right] - 2\\
&= 2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{2}(e^{+1} + e^{-1}) - 2\\
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\tilde{W}(\tau)] = (e^{+1} + e^{-1}) - 2
\end{align}

$\textbf{My Question:}$ It appears $\mathbb{E}[e^{W(\tau)}] = \tfrac{1}{2}(e^{+1} + e^{-1})$, I do not understand why this is the case. I am familiar with the result $\mathbb{E}[\exp(cW(t))] = \exp(\tfrac{1}{2}c^2 t)$ but cannot see the application here. Would someone be able to explain please?

Apologies if this is trivial. All help is appreciated.

Many thanks,

John

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb{E}[e^{W(\tau)}] = \tfrac{1}{2}(e^{+1} + e^{-1})$ is indeed trivial from what you already know and used to show that $\mathbb{E}[W(\tau)] =0$, namely, that $\mathbb P(W(\tau)=+1)=\mathbb P(W(\tau)=-1)=\frac12$.

Comment: @Hello Did, thank you for the comment. It's just clicked, $e^{(W(\tau)=1)}*\mathbb{P}(W(\tau)=1) + e^{(W(\tau)=-1)}*\mathbb{P}(W(\tau)=-1)$. How embarrassing.  But embarrassing or not that's made it concrete. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}W_{\tau}=0$ and $W_{\tau} \in \{1,-1\}$, we have

$$0 = \mathbb{E}(W_{\tau}) = \mathbb{E}(1 \cdot 1_{\{W_{\tau}=1\}} + (-1) \cdot 1_{\{W_{\tau}=-1\}}) = \mathbb{P}(W_{\tau}=1) - \mathbb{P}(W_{\tau}=-1).$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{P}(W_{\tau}=1) = \mathbb{P}(W_{\tau}=-1) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

This implies

$$\mathbb{E}f(W_{\tau}) = \frac{1}{2} (f(1)+f(-1))$$

for any measurable function $f$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I like the way you have phrased it. Appreciated.

Comment: @JohnSmith You are welcome.

Comment: There is a little more work to be done before claiming $W_\tau \in \{1,-1\}$, since $\tau$ is an infimum.  First one must show that $\tau < \infty$ almost surely, that is, that the set $\{t \ge 0 : |W_t| = 1\}$ is nonempty with probability 1.  Then one must show that if $\tau$ is the infimum of a set of times $t$ at which $|W_t| = 1$, we have $|W_\tau| = 1$ as well (it follows from continuity).  For some people these facts would be obvious, but a beginning student should check them carefully.

Comment: @NateEldredge You are right; thanks for your helpful comment.