# Expectation of a Wiener process at a Stopping Time - 2

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I am working through an answer to the following question and I do not understand a statement given towards the end of the solution, specifically why $\tilde{W}(\sigma) = 1$.

(This question is related to my previous post [Expectation of a Wiener process at a Stopping Time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249698/expectation-of-a-wiener-process-at-a-stopping-time) but I believe it may be viewed without reference to that post).
\begin{align}
\end{align}

$\textbf{Question:}$ Define the following stochastic process
\begin{align}
\tilde{W}(t) := W(t) + \int_{0}^{t} e^{W(s)}\mathbb{1}_{\{|W(s)\le 1\}}\,ds \quad \forall \, t \in [0,T]
\end{align}
For the stopping time $\sigma := \inf\{t \ge 0 : W(t) = 1 - \int_{0}^{t} e^{W(s)}\mathbb{1}_{\{|W(s)\le 1\}}\,ds \}$ compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[e^{-\sigma/2} \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\end{align}
$\textbf{Solution:}$ Define $M(t) = \exp\left(\tilde{W}(t) - \tfrac{1}{2}t \right)$ as a martingale $(M(t) : t \ge 0)$.

Then from the $\textbf{optional}$ $\textbf{sampling}$ $\textbf{theorem}$,
\begin{align}
1 = \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[M(0) \right] = \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[M(t\wedge \sigma) \right]
\end{align}

Moreover, we have $M(t \wedge \sigma) \rightarrow M(\sigma)$ $\mathcal{Q}$-a.s. as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and it follows that
\begin{align}
&|M(t \wedge \sigma| \le \exp\left(\tilde{W}(t \wedge \sigma) - \tfrac{1}{2}(t\wedge \sigma)\right) \le \exp\left(\tilde{W}(t\wedge \sigma) \right) \le \exp(1),\\
&\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[\exp(1)\right] = \exp(1) < \infty
\end{align}

By Lebesgue's theorem of dominated convergence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[M(\sigma)\right] = \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} M(t \wedge \sigma) \right] = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[M(t\wedge \sigma) \right] = 1
\end{align}
On the other hand, since $\tilde{W}(\sigma) = 1$ we have 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[M(\sigma) \right] &= \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[e^{1 - \tfrac{1}{2}\sigma} \right]\\
1 &= \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[e^{1 - \tfrac{1}{2}\sigma} \right]\\
\end{align}
so,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}}\left[e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}\sigma} \right] = \frac{1}{e}
\end{align}

$\textbf{My Question}:$ It is stated above that $\tilde{W}(\sigma) = 1$, unfortunately I cannot see why this is the case. Could someone please explain why this is?

All help is appreciated.

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step you are asking about is just algebra:

$$W(\sigma)=1-\int_0^\sigma e^{W(s)} 1_{|W(s)| \leq 1} ds$$

Substitute that into the definition of $\tilde{W}$:

$$\tilde{W}(\sigma)=1-\int_0^\sigma e^{W(s)} 1_{\{ |W(s)| \leq 1\}} ds + \int_0^\sigma e^{W(s)} 1_{\{ |W(s)| \leq 1 \}} ds = 1.$$

Comment: Argh!!!!!! I need break. Dreaming about martingales. Thank you Ian.